# maven-dependency-plugin not showing test-scoped dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I'm attempting to display the full tree of dependencies for a project I'm working on using the maven-dependency-plugin version 3.1.2 from the command line, but the `mvn dependency:tree` goal (nor any of the other goals from the maven-dependency-plugin) is not showing the `test` dependencies. The documentation of the plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) states that all scopes are included by default, so using the -Dscope=test shouldn't be necessary (but when adding this parameter, the output doesn't change).

I've run this with a clean .m2 repository, using no settings.xml file (to ensure that all artifacts are coming directly from `repo.maven.apache.org`).

I'm running using maven 3.6.2 on a linux environment (CentOS 7) and using Oracle Java 1.8.0_144

Here's my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.sw-eval</groupId>
  <artifactId>cayenne-eval</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cayenne</groupId>
      <artifactId>cayenne-server</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cayenne</groupId>
      <artifactId>cayenne-di</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cayenne</groupId>
      <artifactId>cayenne-dbsync</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cayenne</groupId>
      <artifactId>cayenne-client</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.M2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here's the output I receive from running the command `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.sw-eval:cayenne-eval >----------------------
[INFO] Building cayenne-eval 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ cayenne-eval ---
[INFO] com.sw-eval:cayenne-eval:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.cayenne:cayenne-server:jar:4.2.M2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cayenne:cayenne-di:jar:4.2.M2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cayenne:cayenne-dbsync:jar:4.2.M2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cayenne:cayenne-project:jar:4.2.M2:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.java.dev.inflector:inflector:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.cayenne:cayenne-client:jar:4.2.M2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.caucho:hessian:jar:4.0.63:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.cayenne:cayenne-rop-server:jar:4.2.M2:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.cayenne:cayenne-web:jar:4.2.M2:compile
[INFO]       \- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.951 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-25T08:53:17-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When referring to the `cayenne-server` pom, however, there are many dependencies marked as `test` which are not shown in the output (specifically, the following are direct dependencies of `cayenne-server`, see https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.cayenne/cayenne-server/4.2.M2/jar):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cayenne.build-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>cayenne-test-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mockrunner</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockrunner-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <!-- this one have old Xerces dependency that clashes with JDK's one -->
                    <groupId>nekohtml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

So, is there something that I'm missing that needs to be enabled to show these `test`-scoped dependencies, and / or is this a weird artifact unique to the `cayenne-server` dependency?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies of scope `test` are not transitive.

The `test` dependencies of your dependencies are not part of your dependency tree. They are ignored by Maven.